# Etymologies of "basilisk" and "basilica"

Tags: etymology, history

I recently confused a "[basilica](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/basilica)" with a "[basilisk](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/basilisk)", with the former being a church building and the latter being a mythical snake-like creature.

The similarities of the two words made me curious of their origins. But the etymology of both words (from the Wiktionary links) say the same thing: Latin-*basilica* and Greek-*basilike*, meaning "royal".

What is the connection of this meaning with "mythical snake-like dragon with a deadly gaze"?

Comment: +1 for an unexpected commonality. BTW, don't confuse mosques with mosquitoes. Or burros with burritos.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com) is generally considered to be the more verbose and reliable reference for etymologies. Its entry for [basilisk](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=basilisk) reads:

> c.1300, from Latin basiliscus, from Greek basiliskos "little king," dim. of **basileus "king"** (see Basil); said by Pliny to have been **so called because of a crest or spot on its head resembling a crown.**

[Basilica's](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=basilica) entry reads:

> 1540s, from Latin basilica "building of a court of justice," and, by extension, church built on the plan of one, from Greek (stoa) basilike "royal (portal)," the portico of the **archon basileus**, the **official who dispensed justice** in Athens, **from basileus "king"** (see Basil). In Rome, applied specifically to the seven principal churches founded by Constantine.

Wikipedia's entries for [basilisk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basilisk) and [basilica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basilica) confirm the *royal* connection that the two words share. The former includes an excerpt from the aforementioned Pliny's [encyclopaedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_History_%28Pliny%29) published in ~79CE:

> There is the same power also in the serpent called the basilisk. It is produced in the province of Cyrene, being not more than twelve fingers in length. **It has a white spot on the head, strongly resembling a sort of a diadem**.

Comment: Basilisks are also known as the kings of serpents (thus Harry Potter, even).

Comment: So the phonetic difference -- the /sk/ at the end -- comes from the Greek diminutive suffix. It frequently happens that the diminutive of a noun survives where its original doesn't, as in L apiculus > Fr abeille, Here they both came through, though in different ways.

Comment: Lots of English and other European language words come from Gk _basileus_ 'king', including the herb _basil_ and the name _Basil_.

Answer (score 3):

According to various dictionary sources, it appears to be so-called because it is described as having a crest or crown-like spot on its head.  Hence the link to 'royal.'

[E.g.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/basilisk)

> Origin:  1250–1300; Middle English  < Latin basiliscus  < Greek
>   basilískos  princeling, basilisk, equivalent to basil ( eús ) king +
>   -iskos  diminutive suffix; allegedly so named from a crownlike white spot on its head

Answer (score -1):

The basilica building is in the shape of a serpent wearing a crown. There's the connection.

Check this pic I uploaded for more undeniable proof.

[image]

Comment: The "serpent" only works if you selectively crop the building's contours (as the black lines do). If you simply view the image from above (as you can on Google maps), it doesn't really resemble a serpent at all.

Comment: Besides, this is one instance of a basilica, and nowhere near as old as the first ones, which were much more simplistic and straightforward.